# Theming Emacs's mode-line like Mac version in Linux

Tags: mode-line, themes

How can I make Emacs24's mode-line to show like how its displayed in Mac version of Emacs?

Is there any package or script or config for this?

I mean like this image:

[image]

Note: I know this has nothing with Mac but the `brew install` version in there is like this & I just to explain myself;

Comment: That's not the minibuffer, that's mode-line. You should try one of these packages: https://github.com/Malabarba/smart-mode-line https://github.com/milkypostman/powerline

Comment: May also be worth clarifying that that's not anything specific to a Mac build of Emacs, whichever one you're using; it's just a package that you can install on any Emacs new enough to support it.

Comment: @AaronMiller: Yes but default install of emacs on Mac (`brew install emacs`) gave me that and I didn't know how should I describe it; Thanks anyway

Comment: @caisah: Yes :) ; I'm new in emacs and I can't find any source for it's terminology; excuse me ; Thank you very much

Comment: I find it hard to believe that Emacs installed through brew comes with *that* kind of configuration.  Are you sure these are not remnants of you playing around with starterkits?

Comment: @wasamasa It doesn't.  That's definitely custom configuration.

Comment: @wasamasa: I don't know; I'm not using Mac just someone whom uses mac & had such a mod-line which I asked said so !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That particular mode line can be installed using `power-line` project and my horrid Lisp configuration code in my [dot-files](https://github.com/howardabrams/dot-files/blob/master/emacs-mode-line.org) project on Github.